# Polymer undefined property in custom function

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I use **Polymer** (v1.0) and I want to create a simple element which can show me some extra content **depending on a property** and it has to work with **multiple values** - a.k.a simple "**switch**".

I wrote this code.

```
...
    <span>{{for}}</span>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{checkFor('alfa')}}">
        hi !!!
    </template>
</template>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "...",

        properties: {
            for: String,
            user: String,
            manager: {
                type: Boolean,
                notify: true
            }
        },

        attached: function() {
            this.textContent = 'Hello World, my user is ' + (this.user || 'nobody') + '.\n' +
                    'This user is ' + (this.manager ? '' : 'not') + ' a manager and he likes ' + this.for + '.';
        },


        checkFor: function (aaa) {
            // return aaa === this.for;

            this.textContent = 'Hello World, my user is ' + (this.user || 'nobody') + '.\n' +
                    'This user is ' + (this.manager ? '' : 'not') + ' a manager and he likes ' + this.for + '.';
        }
    });
</script>
```

My function `checkFor` is used to check if a value I want to have (for example 'alfa') is equal with element property/attribute `for`.

But it doesn't worked at all so I tried to check values using console.log(). After than I discovered variable `aaa` contains 'alfa' and variable `this.for` contains `undefined`.

Then I copied some output code I found which use element properties and it also did not work. If I run the same code in `attached` function it works fine.

**How can I use element properties in custom functions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time your `checkFor` function is called, `this.for` has not been defined yet. You can pass in `for` as a parameter to the function, as described in the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#dependent-properties).

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{checkFor('alfa', for)}}">
```

Comment: This works, thank you. But this makes from the function more like equals(a, b) function. Is there any way how to avoid use the second argument?

Comment: You don't need to modify the function code. You can leave it as it is in your example and ignore the second parameter. Only the binding needs to be updated. Adding the parameter in the binding will cause the function to be executed only when the for parameter is not undefined and whenever it changes.